# Grails: How do I create a static array

Tags: grails, static

I'm new to grails. I need to create a static array which needs to be filled with certain items on startup. i.e

```
public class kingUtil {

    public static String[] overlordArray = new String[]

    static def init() {
        overlordArray[0] = "foos"
        overlordArray[1] = "roh"
        overlordArray[2] = "dah"
    }
}
```

So I put the utility groovy class in sources and I intended to call init() from bootstrap.
However, bootstrap cannot recognize the class name, like it can't reach it or something. What's the best way to establish implement application-scope statics in grails.

Comment: where do you put your `kingUtil`?

Comment: The way you have described it is correct.

Comment: Almost every time Bootstrap has been spooky for me it's due to me forgetting to import something, in your case kingUtil.

Do you have a stacktrace?

Comment: It's probably not the direct cause of this problem but as you say you're new to Grails, you should really get into the habit of naming _classes_ with UpperCamelCase and fields and methods with lowerCamelCase - there's various places in the Grails internals that depend on these sorts of conventions.

Comment: Initiate the Array with the initial size, in this case, 3. Use `KingUtil.init()` in Bootstrap. Debug adding a `println` entering the static method `init()`. It worked for me, `bootStrap` was able to recognize the class. Note: KingUtil is inside `src\groovy`.

Comment: Consider creating a bean container that has those values and inject into your class instead.

Comment: "What's the best way to establish implement application-scope statics in grails." - This is application configuration. Use the Grails configuration system.